# Retrieving Disk information from remote server C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, wmi, remote-access, diskspace

Hi we are working on C# framework v4.0 asp.net mvc  application on a distributed structure. We are using Server1 for image Server2 for mysql database and Server3 for web. My task is to get free disk space and total disk space from all three servers and to display on web admin page. I know how to display disk space for localhost using WMI. I want to display Server1 and Server3 disk information which have static ip (All three server have remote desktop and sharing enabled). but i get

```
Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED))
```

here is my code

```
ManagementScope scope = new ManagementScope("\\\\Server IP\\root\\cimv2");
scope.Connect();

ObjectQuery query = new ObjectQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_OperatingSystem");
SelectQuery query1 = new SelectQuery("Select * from Win32_LogicalDisk");

ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(scope, query);

ManagementObjectCollection queryCollection = searcher.Get();

ManagementObjectSearcher searcher1 = new ManagementObjectSearcher(scope, query1);
ManagementObjectCollection queryCollection1 = searcher1.Get();

foreach (ManagementObject m in queryCollection)
{
    // Display the remote computer information
    Console.WriteLine("Computer Name : {0}",
                      m["csname"]);
    Console.WriteLine("Windows Directory : {0}",
                      m["WindowsDirectory"]);
    Console.WriteLine("Operating System: {0}",
                      m["Caption"]);
    Console.WriteLine("Version: {0}", m["Version"]);
    Console.WriteLine("Manufacturer : {0}", m["Manufacturer"]);
    Console.WriteLine();

}

foreach (ManagementObject mo in queryCollection1)
{
    Console.WriteLine("  Disk Name : {0}", mo["Name"]);
    Console.WriteLine("   Disk Size : {0}", mo["Size"]);
    Console.WriteLine("  FreeSpace : {0}", mo["FreeSpace"]);
    Console.WriteLine("  Disk DeviceID : {0}", mo["DeviceID"]);
    Console.WriteLine("  Disk VolumeName : {0}", mo["VolumeName"]);
    Console.WriteLine("  Disk SystemName : {0}", mo["SystemName"]);
    Console.WriteLine("Disk VolumeSerialNumber : {0}", mo["VolumeSerialNumber"]);
    Console.WriteLine();
}
Console.ReadLine();
```

but when compile goes to line scope.Connect(); 
then it throws exception access denied

I have tried [this article using Dcomcnfg.exe security](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa389284(v=vs.85).aspx) but still cant get rid of this exception

i have also tried

```
ConnectionOptions options = new ConnectionOptions();
options.Username = @"Admin-PC\username";
options.Password = @"password";
options.Impersonation = ImpersonationLevel.Impersonate;
options.Authentication = AuthenticationLevel.Connect;
options.EnablePrivileges = true;
options.Timeout = new TimeSpan(0, 60, 0);
ManagementScope scope = new ManagementScope("\\\\IP\\root\\cimv2", options);
```

Comment: i think i cant configure dcom security properly

Comment: http://serverfault.com/questions/28520/which-permissions-rights-does-a-user-need-to-have-wmi-access-on-remote-machines

Comment: i have tried all the steps in article but still getting access denied

Comment: stack trace information    at System.Management.ManagementException.ThrowWithExtendedInfo(ManagementStatus errorCode)
   at System.Management.ManagementScope.InitializeGuts(Object o)
   at System.Management.ManagementScope.Initialize()
   at System.Management.ManagementScope.Connect()

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure *Allow remote connections to this computer* is enabled.
2. Make sure WMI is enabled in WindowsFirewall --> Allowed Apps.
3. Make sure CIMV2 folder is accessble by admin in WMI Control properties.
4. Make sure WMI and RPC services are running.
5. User has admin rights on remote system

Comment: now getting this exception User Credentials cannot be used for local connections (im remotely connected to the pc)

Comment: @skhurams I think you are trying to query local system, While querying local system no need to pass credentials

Comment: its not localsystem as i have given server ip  in first line ManagementScope scope = new ManagementScope("\\\\Server IP\\root\\cimv2");

Comment: if i had to get local system information then it was easy